# Filemaker Pro and generating stats in html

Tags: mysql, database, filemaker

I am using Filemaker pro 12 to manage a small database. What I need is to generate some stats based on the data in the database and update an HTML page so at any point I get updated stats. How would I do this ? I am a newbie when it comes to databases.

I am not necessarily sold on filemaker and if there is a better database option that has easier options available for autoupdating a website from the database, generate real time data etc. I am open to hearing about them. Thanks in advance for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

If the FileMaker database is hosted using FileMaker server, you can output information from a FileMaker database to a web page using the FileMaker API for PHP. You just need to enable access via PHP in FileMaker server, and write the appropriate PHP code to pull out the data you want. You probably want the FileMaker server and the web server to be at the same location as there can be a bit of overhead going between them.

Advantage of the above is that it is real-time. However, if your web site is high traffic, it could bog down your FileMaker system.

Another way would be to build the web page using MySQL. FileMaker can access MySQL tables and then manipulate them almost as if they are local tables. You could have a script that periodically imports data into the MySQL table from the local tables. You could run the script as often as you want to keep the data up-to-date, but it wouldn't be as up-to-date as a live system. On the other hand, there wouldn't need to be a connection to the FileMaker database every time someone viewed your web page.

If you need something simpler and less current, you could write the entire page using FileMaker calculations, then manually export the field to an html file as required and manually upload it to the web server.

There are probably many other ways. You haven't been very specific in your requirements.